# Find the nth number formed using 2 set bits

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given an *n*, I need to find the nth number that can be formed using just 2 bits.

To clarify better, the sequence basically goes like 3,5,6,9,10..

ie. If n=1, answer=3 etc. (Note that the answer has to be printed in its decimal form)

The following is what I've done based on the answer I got (and it still gives me wrong answer for some hidden test cases)

```
using namespace std;

#define MAX 10000
#define MOD 1000000007

long long int m[MAX+1];
long long int sum;

long long int binary_search(long long int n)
{
   long long int low=0,high=MAX,mid;
   while(low<high)
   {
     mid=low+(high-low+1)/2;
     if(m[mid]<=n)
        low=mid;
     else
        high=mid-1;
   }
   return low;
}

int main() 
{
  m[0]=1;
  for(long long int i=1;i<=MAX;i++)
    m[i]=m[i-1]+i;

  long long int n,k,l;
  int t;
  scanf("%d",&t);
  for(int test=0;test<t;test++)
  {
    scanf("%lld",&n);
    k=binary_search(n);
    //cout<<m[k]<<" ";
    l=n-m[k];
    cout<<((1<<k+1)%MOD+(1<<l)%MOD)%MOD<<"\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The constraints are 1 <= T <= 10^6, 1 <= N <= 10^14.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Do you want to create an algorithm that tells you which number you're at depending on the user input ?

Comment: Don't write decimals for a question about binary representation... If you write it 11, 101, 110, 1001, 1010, 1100, etc, the problem is quite easy (count how many k-digit numbers you get). And use a (unsigned) long long to represent a number with more than 32 bits.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: In the end, I need to print its decimal form. So, I'll have to store it somehow?

Comment: Writing in decimals is what printf, cout<< etc do for you at the end. Before that, you need to find the right algorithm to get the number in a long long.

Comment: You can maintain two variables, say a and b, representing the position of the two set bits (*i.e.* for 5 whose binary representation is 101, we would have a = 2, b = 0). The number represented by an (a, b) pair will be 2^a + 2^b. This representation should not cause problems when representing numbers in the range of 10^14 (if the datatype is long long int).

Comment: @qwertyman: If I understand correctly, the OP needs to represent the first 10^14 numbers that have only two bits set. So we're not talking about "numbers in the range of 10^14", but rather, numbers in the range of 2^sqrt(10^14) or so.

Comment: @ruakh indeed, i misread, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explore patterns:

There is one valid number with MSB (most significant bit) index  = 1
There are two valid numbers with MSB (most significant bit) index = 2
There are three valid numbers with MSB (most significant bit) index = 3   (1001, 1010, 1100)
...

(there are k places after MSB with  index k)

So you can easily find index of MSB for given n - just exploit sum of arithmetic progression

When MSB=k is known, subtract sum of AP until k from n to get index of the second non-zero bit (l)

`Result = (1 << k) + (1 << l)`